# Run python program in jenkins job

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to run below code in jenkins job, code is to delete files older than 30 days from a directory in ftp server.
I created freestyle project job in jenkins and in build section I have selected "Execute shell" and I have added below code.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import ftputil
host = ftputil.FTPHost('host', 'user', 'pass')
mypath = '/path/directory'
now = time.time()
host.chdir(mypath)
names = host.listdir(host.curdir)
for name in names:
      if host.path.isfile(name):
         host.remove(name)
host.close()
```

I am facing below error on build

```
Building remotely on docker-4 (maven linux docker) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Capacity/folder/Test_job
[Test_job] $ /usr/bin/python /tmp/jenkins8422988908580909797.sh
  File "/tmp/jenkins8422988908580909797.sh", line 6
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /tmp/jenkins8422988908580909797.sh on line 6, but no encoding declared;
```

and I also tried with "Execute python script" build option I am facing similar error like below.

```
 Building remotely on docker-4 (maven linux docker) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Capacity/folder/Test_job
    [Test_job] $ python /tmp/jenkins5375363980435767190.py
      File "/tmp/jenkins5375363980435767190.py", line 6
    SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /tmp/jenkins5375363980435767190.py on line 6, but no encoding declared;
```

I am new to jenkins job and python, can any one guide how can I resolve this issue.

2) If I select jenkins pipeline job how can I call this python code from jenkinsfile.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try?  I see nothing that would prevent this from working from a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ftputil globally.

```
pip install ftputil
```

or

```
sudo pip install ftputil
```

The following shell script works with no error, once I installed ftputil globally with sudo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import ftputil
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about this python program. If you want to execute it from shell. Then create shell script file e.g. `python_prog.sh` then, change permissions `chmod +x python_prog.sh python_prog.py`

**python_prog.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

python python_prog.py
```

Finally, run the script from terminal `. python_prog.sh` or `./python_prog.sh`